# pandas apply map function throwing error when applied lower() method on the data series

Tags: pandas, lambda, apply

For the below code:

```
# Reading the input
import ast,sys
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
# Storing the names in a variable 'name'
name = input_list[0]
# Storing the responses in a variable 'repsonse'
response = input_list[1]

import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': name,'Response': response})
```

This input provided is as:

```
['Reetesh', 'Shruti', 'Kaustubh', 'Vikas', 'Mahima', 'Akshay']
['No', 'Maybe', 'yes', 'Yes', 'maybe', 'Yes']
```

And the output needed is like:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3FIi.png
```

And when I tried something like below:

```
def res_map(x):
    return x.map({'Yes': 1, 'yes': 1, 'No': 0, 'no': 0, 'Maybe': 0.5, 'maybe': 0.5})

df[['Response']] = df[['Response']].apply(res_map)

# Print the final DataFrame
print(df)
```

It worked well..

but when I tried something like this:

```
df['Response'] = df['Response'].apply(lambda x: x.str.lower().map({'yes':1.0, 'no':0.0, 'maybe':0.5}))
```

I got an error "str" object does not hap method "map"...

What I did wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `apply` on a DataFrame like `df[['Response']].apply(...)`, the lambda receives the whole `df.Response` column at once so you can use Series methods like `str` and `map`.

If you instead `apply` on a Series like `df['Response'].apply(...)`, the lambda receives individual strings of `df.Response` instead of the whole `df.Response` column, so the mapping needs to be changed accordingly:

```py
mapping = {'yes':1.0, 'no':0.0, 'maybe':0.5}
df['Response'] = df['Response'].apply(lambda x: mapping[x.lower()])

#        Name  Response
# 0   Reetesh       0.0
# 1    Shruti       0.5
# 2  Kaustubh       1.0
# 3     Vikas       1.0
# 4    Mahima       0.5
# 5    Akshay       1.0
```